# Unable to Remove Buttons in UITableView Edit Mode

Tags: uitableview, swift

When my UITableView is in edit mode and I press the delete button (-), I  hide the Edit button in the row and show a Delete and Cancel button.

If the Cancel button is pressed I am fine since it triggers the button's Cancel handler and I re-display the Edit button.

However if the user presses within the row (not the Cancel or Delete buttons), the row exits from delete mode without allowing me to show the Edit button.

Is there some event that I can detect when delete mode is exited or when the row is pressed when in delete mode?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> [AnyObject]!
{
// hide the Edit button in this row
self.editButtons[indexPath.row].hidden = true

// create a Cancel button to abort delete
var cancelAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Cancel", handler:  
{( 
    action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in

// if Cancel pressed, show the Edit button again 
self.editButtons[indexPath.row].hidden = false

// reload the row to get rid of the Delete and Cancel buttons   
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

return
})

var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler:
{( 
action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
    println("Delete not implemented")
    return
})
return [deleteAction, cancelAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `willTransitionToState` function inside the `UITableViewCell` to keep track of the state changes. 
You have to keep track of the `previousState`, to check whether your delete button is being hidden.

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    var previousState : UITableViewCellStateMask = UITableViewCellStateMask.allZeros

    override func willTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
        if state & UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingEditControlMask != nil
        {
            if previousState & UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask != nil
            {
                println("hiding delete")
                /* Send a notification or call a function by setting a 
                   delegate from the view controller.*/
            }

        }
        previousState = state
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the right answer. It is hitting the function when I am exiting edit mode. However I am new to Swift and need to figure out how to set and call a delegate in the view controller.